# From ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

After installing the CKEditor from pip, I try to import CKEditor from models but it keeps giving me `ImportError cannot import name get_default_renderer`.

After I followed the CKEditor documentation thoroughly, it still gives me the error. Is it my Django version 1.10 problem or the thoroughly version 5.6.1? Can someone give me direction?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.RichTextUploadingField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank= True, null = True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,  redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import CommentForm
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
  posts =   Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts })

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post':post, 'form':form }, )
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'app',
  'cart',
  'orders',
  'blog',
  'ckeditor_uploader',
  # Add your apps here to enable them
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

#CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
#    'default':{
#        'toolbar': None,
#        }
#    }
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import django.contrib.auth.views
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^cart', include('cart.urls')),
   url(r'^orders', include('orders.urls')),
   url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
   url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
   url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### error page

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_renderer'
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.  <locals>.wrapper at 0x0421B4F8>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-    packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
 fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-   packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
 autoreload.raise_last_exception()
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
 six.reraise(*_exception)
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-  packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 \lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\stylop\source\repos\alfiez\alfiez\blog\models.py", line 4, in <module>
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\ckeditor_uploader\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
 from ckeditor import fields
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\ckeditor\fields.py", line 6, in <module>
 from .widgets import CKEditorWidget
 File "C:\Users\stylop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\ckeditor\widgets.py", line 12, in <module>
 from django.forms.widgets import get_default_renderer
 ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_renderer'
```

Comment: Upload your error page

Comment: error page posted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If all you want is to have a simple WYSIWYG editor. django-ckeditor is perfect for you.

`pip install django-ckeditor`

Add `ckeditor` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Run the `collectstatic` management command: `$ ./manage.py collectstatic.` This will copy static CKEditor required media resources into the directory given by the STATIC_ROOT setting

In your `models.py` import `from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField` and use it directly like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   content = RichTextField()
```

Also import in your `forms.py` `from ckeditor.fields import RichTextFormField`
and use it directly like

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = Foo
          fields = ['content']
          widgets = {
             'content': RichTextFormField(),
          }
```

You should have something like this [image: ck-editor working with Django-Admin]
For more configuration you can add this to your `settings.py` and configure it to suit what you want

```
# CKEditor Configuration Settings

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        # 'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'width': '461px',
        'height': 'auto',
        # 'toolbar_Custom': [
        #     ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
        #     ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
        # ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting CKEditor and facility upload image

1. `pip install django-ckeditor`
2. add ckeditor and ckeditor_uploader in file setting.py

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...
       'ckeditor',
       'ckeditor_uploader',
       ...
   ]
   ```
3. add code below in file setting.py

   ```
   CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
   'portal_config': {
       # 'skin': 'moono',
       # 'skin': 'office2013',
       'toolbar_Basic': [
           ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
       ],
       'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
           {'name': 'document', 'items': [
               'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'
           ]},
           {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': [
               'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'
           ]},
           {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
           {'name': 'forms',
            'items': [
                'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea',
                'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField'
            ]},
           '/',
           {'name': 'basicstyles',
            'items': [
                'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript',
                'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'
            ]},
           {'name': 'paragraph',
            'items': [
                'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent',
                '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft',
                'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-',
                'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language'
            ]},
           {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
           {'name': 'insert',
            'items': [
                'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule',
                'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'
            ]},
           '/',
           {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
           {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
           {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
           {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
           '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
           {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
               # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
               'Preview',
               'Maximize',

           ]},
       ],
       'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
       # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
       # 'height': 291,
       # 'width': '100%',
       # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
       # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
       # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
       # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
       'tabSpaces': 4,
       'extraPlugins': ','.join([
           'uploadimage',  # the upload image feature
           # your extra plugins here
           'div',
           'autolink',
           'autoembed',
           'embedsemantic',
           'autogrow',
           # 'devtools',
           'widget',
           'lineutils',
           'clipboard',
           'dialog',
           'dialogui',
           'elementspath'
       ]),
       }
   }
   ```
4. in model

   ```
   from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


   class Article(models.Model):
    body = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='portal_config')
   ```

[image]