# Import ckeditor could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am trying to use RichTextFields through ckeditor in my django project. What I initially thought would be an easy task has caused me nightmares.

I am able to pip install django-ckeditor easily. I have followed all the required steps as per https://pytutorial.com/django-ckeditor including adding to settings.py, adding MEDIA_ROOT etc etc. I have collected static and ran migrations and still nothing seems to be working. I get to the final step where I am importing in my models.py but I get a squiggly yellow underline that says "Import "ckeditor_uploader.fields" could not be resolved".

settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

urls.py:

```
from projects.views import projects
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include ('projects.urls')),
    path('users/', include ('users.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from users.models import Profile
from *ckeditor_uploader.fields* import RichTextUploadingField


class Project (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default.jpg")
```

Comment: see if this helps ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322221/8401179

Comment: hey Sangeeth, thanks for helping- this is exactly what I have done... still not working :/

Comment: Hello @SamOcean did it give you an error ?

Comment: Hey @AnkitTiwari yes it gave me: Import "ckeditor_uploader.fields" could not be resolved

Comment: Hello @SamOcean check whether your virtual environment is activated or not if you have one, and try to reinstall ```pip install django-ckeditor```

Comment: The field you seem to be importing is *ckeditor_uploader.fields* and the one in which I have mentioned above, directly imports from CKeditor which is what you have pip installed... I would suggest to try again in those steps